# Magento Destination folder is not writable or does not exists

Tags: magento

I want to upload a PDF to an article on a Webshop. But Magento returns the following error:

> Destination folder is not writeable or does not exists.

It's at: Catalogus -> Manage Attachments.

all the folders in the media map has 777 permissions.

I searched whole Google but I don't have a clue..

Answer (score 1):

If you have hosted your application on Linux check whether SE Linux is in permissive mode or not.

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS 8! thank you. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/enable-selinux-centos